# Is it possible to construct arbitrary direct sums in the category of R modules?

Tags: category-theory, modules, homological-algebra, direct-sum, abelian-categories

Let R be a ring with unit, $X$ a set and $\{ M_x \}_{x \in X}$ a family of $R$ modules. I will try to construct the direct sum $\bigoplus_{x \in X}Mx$

First, as a set, $\bigoplus_{x \in X}M_x$ is necessarily a product of the sets $M_x$, because the forgetful functor $U: R Mod \rightarrow Set$ preserves limits. So we set $\bigoplus_{x \in X}M_x = \Pi_{x \in X}M_x$

Any inclusion $\iota_{a}: M_a \rightarrow \Pi_{x \in X}M_x$ in a direct sum has to satisfy:

$$\pi_x \circ \iota_a = \begin{cases} 1, \text{if } x = a \\ 0, \text{if } x \neq a \end{cases}$$

this uniquely determines $\iota_a$.And it can be show $\iota_a$ is a R-mod morphism.

Is $\{\iota_x: M_x \rightarrow \Pi_x M_x \}_{x \in X}$ a coproduct? If so, I will have succeeded in constructing arbitrary direct sum.

Comment: The correct construction of the coproduct of a family of $R$-modules $M_i$ is $\oplus_{i\in I}M_I = \{\sum_{i\in I}a_i| a_i\in M_i, a_i=0 \text{ except finitely many } i \}$

Comment: The direct sum is a colimit. The underlying set of the direct sum of infinitely many non-zero modules is not the product.

Comment: You can tell your construction is wrong because a coproduct would necessarily be generated by the images $\iota_a(M_a)$ by a standard argument, yet the images of your $\iota_a$ do not generate the direct product. However, the submodule that they generate *is* the direct sum/coproduct. Your error is that the direct sum is a coproduct, hence a colimit. The forgetful functor does not tell you what the underlying set "should" be.

Comment: Arturo Magidin: are you saying that a direct sum of an infinite famility of modules doesn't has to be a product of this family?

Comment: @Lucas: The direct sum of an infinite family of nontrivial modules not only "doesn't have to be a product", it **never** is their product. Abelian categories only require the *binary* biproduct to be both a product and a coproduct, and from that you get that *finite* products agree with finite coproducts. They say nothing about infinite families. P.S. If you don't use the `@`, you don't ping me even if you write my name.

Comment: @Arturo Magidin: I see, when a family of objects $\{ X_i\}_{i \in I}$ of an abelian category is infinity, direct sum means the same as coproduct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The direct product $\Pi_{x\in X} M_x $ is not a coproduct if the index set $X$ is infinite. To see this, let
$$A = \{(m_x)_{x\in X} \mid m_x = 0 \text{ for all but finitely many } x\in X\}\subset \Pi_{x\in X}M_x,$$
and let $f_x:M_x\to \Pi_{x\in X}M_x$ and $q_x: M_x\to A$ be the natural inclusions. Now show the following:

1. If $\Pi_{x\in X}M_x$ is the coproduct, then the maps $f_x$ are the associated inclusions.
2. If $X$ is infinite, then there is no map $g:\Pi_{x\in X}\to A$ such that $q_x = g\circ f_x$ for all $x\in X$.

Alternatively, prove directly that $A$ with the associated maps $q_x$ is the coproduct. Note that $A\simeq \Pi_{x\in X}M_x$ if and only if the index set $X$ is finite.

Comment: By saying that $f_x: M_x \rightarrow \Pi_{x \in X}M_x$ is the natural inclusion, do you mean that given $m_x \in M_x$, $\pi_x(f_x(m_x)) = m_x$, $\pi_y(f_x(m_x)) = 0$ for $y \neq x$? Did I get it right?

Comment: In that case, Would $q_x$ be obtained by restricting the codomain of $f_x$?

Comment: @Lucas Yes, you are right about both. Explicitly, $\Pi_{x\in X}M_x$ is the set of functions $a:X\to \bigcup_{x\in X}M_x$ such that $a(x)\in M_x$ for all $x\in X$, and $f_x:M_x\to \Pi_{x\in X}M_x$ is the map sending $m\in M_x$ to the element $m\delta_x\in\Pi_{x\in X}M_x,\: y\mapsto m\delta_{x,y}$. I.e., $f_x(m)$ is $m$ at $x$, and zero at all $y\in X\setminus\{x\}$. And $q_x$ is, as you say, the co-restriction of $f_x$ to $A$.